# Is $\beta$ a basis of vector space $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Let $V=\{p\in\mathbb{R}[X]:\deg(p)\leq n\}$, knowing that $\{1,X,\dots,X^n\}$ is a basis of $V$, determine whether $\beta=\{1,X,X^2+1,X^3+X,\dots,X^n+X^{n-2}\}$ is a basis of $V$.
Consider: $\quad  c_0+c_1X+c_2(X^2+1)+\dots+c_n(X^n+X^{n-2})=0$
$\implies (c_0+c_2)+(c_1+c_3)X+(c_2+c_4)X^2+\dots+(c_n+c_{n-2})X^{n-2}+c_{n-1}X^{n-1}+c_nX^n=0$
Because of the definition of the zero polynomial, it must follow, that all coefficients $\quad c_0,c_1,\dots,c_n=0$, meaning $\beta$ is linearly independent.
It is given that $\{1,X,\dots,X^n\}$ is a basis of $V$, so $\dim(V)=\dim(\{1,X,\dots,X^n\})=n+1$. Because $|\beta|=|\{1,X,\dots,X^n\}|,\;\dim(V)=\dim(\beta)$. Therefore $\beta$ is a basis of $V$.
Is this proof correct? Thank you for the help

Comment: Seems ok. Alternatively you can note that the matrix with 1's in the diagonal and 1's placed diagonally two places above the main diagonal is non-singular (because it's triangular with non-zero diagonal entries).

Comment: Your proof is fine, I would just add a detail. Instead of saying “definition of the zero polynomial” I would say “as $1,X,...,X^n$ is a basis of V then $c_{0}+c_{2}=...=c_{n}=0$“.

Comment: @JCAA I figured that after rearranging the coefficient, it has the form $p(x)=a_nx^n+...a_1x+a_0=0$ meaning it is a zero polynomial, and because of the definition of the zero polynomial, all coefficients must be zero.

Comment: @Gio so because of the basis that is given, does it follow directly, that all $c_1, ..., c_n=0$ or is there a step in between?

Comment: As $c_{n}=0$ and $c_{n}+c_{n-2}=0$ then $c_{n-2}=0$. You can do the same with $c_{n-1}=0$ and $c_{n-1}+c_{n-3}=0$  until you get that all $c_{i}=0$ for $i=0,...,n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is incomplete. After getting that$$(c_0+c_2)+(c_1+c_3)X+\cdots+(c_{n-2}+c_n)X^{n-2}+c_{n-1}X^{n-1}+c_nX^n=0,$$you can't jump right away to $c_0=c_1=\cdots=c_n=0$. Note that$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}c_0+c_2=0\\c_1+c_3=0\\\vdots\\c_{n-2}+c_n=0\\c_{n-1}=0\\c_n=0.\end{array}\right.$$Now,

- From $c_n=0$ and $c_{n-2}+c_n=0$, you get that $c_{n-2}=0$.
- From $c_{n-1}=0$ and $c_{n-3}+c_{n-1}=0$, you get that $c_{n-3}=0$.
- $\vdots$
- And so on, until you get that $c_0=0$.

Answer (score 0):

More simply, you may consider the determinant of $\beta$ in the standard basis:

$$\det\beta=\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots\dots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  \dots\dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots\dots & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \dots\dots & 0 \\
\vdots & & &  &  \ddots& \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \dots\dots & 1 
\end{vmatrix}$$
It is an upper triangular determinant, so its value is the product of the diagonal element, $1$, which proves $\beta$ is a basis.